# Pretérito perfecto compuesto y Pretérito Perfecto sin expresión temporal

Tags: pretérito, pretérito-perfecto

¿Notan diferencias entre lo siguiente?

> No puedo salir porque me **rompí** el brazo.
>   No puedo salir porque me **he roto** el brazo.

Nótese que ambas expresiones carecen de expresión temporal, pero, ¿es la primera oración gramaticalmente incorrecta?

Answer (score 3):

El español distingue dos tipos de pretéritos perfectos: el pretérito perfecto simple y el pretérito perfecto compuesto. Según la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=qMhy4gwIzDXX2O6nrTx3), el primero denota una acción o un estado de cosas anteriores al momento en que se habla, **sin vinculación con el presente**; mientras que el segundo denota una acción o un estado de cosas anteriores al momento en que se habla, **vinculado con el presente**.

Luego la cuestión fundamental es qué relación guarda con el presente la acción que se está refiriendo. Desde un punto de vista gramatical, en este caso se debería usar el pretérito perfecto compuesto (*me he roto el brazo*) porque se está estableciendo una relación más que evidente entre romperse el brazo y el presente (*no poder salir*).

Ahora bien, también es verdad que más frecuentemente que no, los hablantes hacen uso de su idioma independientemente de lo que diga una academia. Así, el pretérito perfecto simple (*me rompí*) está mucho más extendido en Latino América, mientras que el pretérito perfecto compuesto (*me he roto*) lo está en España (obviando variantes regionales), y esto independientemente de la relación que guarde la acción con el momento presente. De hecho, la RAE menciona esta gran variedad de usos como un factor que ha determinado que hoy día ambas formas se consideren igual de correctas.

En conclusión, **ninguna de las frases es gramaticalmente incorrecta**; la elección entre una u otra dependerá en su mayor medida de en dónde te encuentres.

Comment: La RAE no es tan prescriptiva como la gente suele pensar.    De la *Gramática* §23.7b: «Puede, pues, afirmarse que el pretérito perfecto compuesto es la forma verbal cuyos usos muestran mayor variación geográfica en el español de hoy.»  Y de hecho, en cada párrafo en §23.7-8, parece que hay una mixtura diferente de dialectos al que se puede atribuir una u otra distinción entre las dos formas.  Es decir, ambas formas pueden se consideran completamente aceptables por la RAE, según dialectos y otros factores extralingüísticos.

Comment: Buena observación. Ya he modificado mi respuesta.

Comment: Discrepo un poquito, en América acostumbra mas el pretérito perfecto simple tal y como lo dice la rae, el uso del compuesto es para cosas que tienen relación con el presente, «me he roto el brazo» suena a dos cosas, a español de España o a frase a medias «...dos veces en el año» y «me rompí el brazo» suena a que ya está roto y ya, me rompí el brazo y ya, se acabó. Supongo que este significado se desplazó en España, en este caso España es quien funciona diferente (no significa que sea malo sólo es diferente).

Comment: No veo la discrepancia,  ¿no es eso lo que he dicho? Es decir, ninguno de los dos es incorrecto, hay que elegir el que más acorde sea al país en el que uno se encuentre. De la misma forma que allí suena raro el "me he roto", aquí suena raro el "me rompí" porque da la sensación de que se está hablando de un suceso anecdótico (_a los seis años me rompí el brazo_) que no podría durar hasta hoy. Solamente tendría sentido algo como "No puedo salir porque [de pequeño] me rompí el brazo. Desde entonces, me dan miedo los parques de atracciones (suponiendo que la salida es a un parque de atracciones)".

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no hay diferencia entre ambas oraciones en el sentido de la acción del verbo sobre el objeto.
Si hay una diferencia en el sentido del verbo sobre la persona (al menos asi lo aprecio).

El decir me rompí, da a entender a una acción pasada lejana. Al decir: "me rompí" da a entender a una acción de hace 1 o 2 días.
El decir me he roto, da a entender que el acontencimiento o acción acaba de suceder en el momento de la oración.

Ej:
Me rompí....el brazo hace 2 días.
Me he roto el brazo...hace unos minutos.

Recalco que es solo mi apreciación de acuerdo a mi ambiente cultural y es la manera como lo aplicamos.